# Paypal Android SDK 2.3.1 Integration ERROR APP Hanging

Tags: android, paypal

I was using PaypalAndroid SDK 2.2.2 earlier at that time it was working fine,Then I have Updated SDK to **2.3.1** after adding this my application is hanging.
The code which is making app to hang:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PayPalService.class);
```

intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
getActivity().startService(intent);

Comment: @MattJacunski Please look at this issue.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Are you able to solve it..?

Comment: No I spent around 6 to 7 hrs on this but still facing problem @MiteshSardhara

Comment: So what do you think is it from our side or PaypalService class@MiteshSardhara

Comment: I am not sure, but if I run demo example. It is working fine without freezing. Not working in my app. But if I remove this start service code from my app, it is working fine. I am searching for the solution still.

Comment: same here @MiteshSardhara

Comment: Could you please add the screen shot of the app freezing @MiteshSardhara

Comment: This is being looked at within PayPal.

Comment: I have updated sdk to 2.3.3 but still issue is there.I think Paypal service class blocking App main thread.@MattJacunski

Comment: This link provided me a solution...[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25314696/1556997)

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed in 2.3.5.  Please upgrade to the latest version (now 2.5+) to fix.